# Physical Significance of Wigner Equation, Wigner Current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

I am Currently doing a reading about Wigner function in Quantum optics, I learnt  that the Wigner function maps the Quantum mechanical operators to phase space functions in phase space, so we can talk about phase-space in Quantum mechanics, but I also came across about Wigner Equation and Wigner Current density while studying about Wigner function, I am wondering whether it has some physical significance in the field of Quantum Optics.

Comment: Addressed in [206680](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206680/is-there-an-equivalent-of-probability-current-for-the-wigner-distribution) . Further see [158871](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158871/quantum-phase-space/206251#206251) .

Comment: Further significance in [quantum optics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103415/are-they-the-same-thing-wigner-distribution-in-quantum-boltzmann-equation-and-w) . By the way, I fear "Wigner equation" is ill defined. Do you mean the time-evolution equation for the Wigner function? Most people call that one the Moyal equation, even though, of course, Wigner wrote it down first, in a [hardly usable form](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf).

Comment: Yes I am referring to the equation later developed by Moyal.

Comment: Which is also known as Wigner Transport equation, which talks about the time evolution of Wigner function.

Comment: OK, we are on the same page. My point is, as explained in our book, that the  structure of the Wigner flow, modifying the Liouville flow, $J_x=pf/m$  
and $J_p= -f \rm{sinc} ({\hbar \over 2}{\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\partial}}_p {\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\partial}}_x ) ~\partial_x V(x)$ is impenetrable without the cardinal sine formulation of Moyal, and I have seen no end to grief caused by people ignoring its manifest symmetries.